# Why am I getting a RuntimeBinderException using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

The following C# causes a Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.**RuntimeBinderException** on line 2.

```
dynamic element = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{ Key: \"key1\" }");
bool match = "key1".Equals(element.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Member
>   'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; 
>   qualify it with a type name instead

The project references Json.NET 8.0.3

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

I'm able to circumvent the exception by explicitly converting `element.Key` to a `System.String`.

```
bool match = "key1".Equals((string)element.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

When checking `element.Key.GetType()`, a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` is returned.

Why is it that DLR does not seem to know which method to invoke and ends up calling the static method `object.Equals(object, object)`?

#### Edit:

As Amit Kumar Ghosh pointed out, this probably has nothing to do with `dynamic` types, since converting to `System.Object` also causes the exception.

```
bool match = "key1".Equals((object)element.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `"key1".Equals((object)element.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)` raises the same error at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that DLR does not seem to know which method to invoke and ends up calling the static method object.Equals(object, object)?

Because `element.Key` isn't a `string`, but is of type `JToken`, which when inspecting it in the debugger looks an awful lot like a string.

This causes the overload resolution at runtime to pick the best match: the [static `object.Equals(objA, objB)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx), as it *can't* call [`string.Equals(value, comparisonType)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx), because the first parameter isn't a string.

You can reproduce this with any dynamic object's non-string property:

```
dynamic foo = new { Foo = false };
bool equals = "Bar".Equals(foo.Foo, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

Throws the same exception.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the purpose of IDynamicMetaObjectProvider and why this works for ExpandoObject, but not JValue?

Comment: @Biscuits I don't really understand that question. Is your question why with `DeserializeObject<dynamic>` the type of `element.Key` is `JToken` or `JValue`, while with `DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>` it's `string`?

Comment: On second thought, that actually makes sense. I wanted clarity on whether JValue is missing something that could make this work. Also, it seems strange that the DLR is considering a static member when I invoke an instance member.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ExpandoObject?

```
dynamic element = new ExpandoObject();
        element = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>("{ Key: \"key1\" }");            
        bool match = "key1".Equals(element.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

Example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/

Comment: this doesn't answer on why __ends up calling the static method object.Equals(object, object)__